# Google Play in-app purchase security

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase

I have an android app with an in-app purchase.

When a user make a purchase, the app generate a random string.
I use this string as developer payload.
It's saved on the device because I'm not able to use a server.
Every time the app is opened, I'll check if developer payload and this string are equal.

Do you think that is a little more secure or this procedure is useless?